# Scrape weather report from meteofrance.com with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, jwt

**Goal**: scrape weather report from [meteofrance](http://meteofrance.com)

**Used tools**: Python libraries (BeautifulSoup, requests, etc.)

**Problem**: it seems that the weather report is only available after an authentication delivering a JSON Web Token (JWT). Actually, I don't know how to get this token with Python libraries. In other words, do I need to create a session or something like that before make the GET request ?

Answer (score 0):

The token is built from the session cookie.

Doing some reverse engineering of the JS bundles, the JS function to do that is the following

```js
const cookieContents = cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )mfsession=([^;]+)'));
const cookieField = decodeURIComponent(cookieContents[2]);
const derivedToken = cookieField.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function (e) {
    var t = e <= 'Z' ? 65 : 97;
    return String.fromCharCode(t + (e.charCodeAt(0) - t + 13) % 26)
});
```

For example, the cookie

`mfsession=rlWwoTSmplV6VzyhqTIlozI0VvjvLJkaVwbvFSZlAGLvYPW0rKNvBvWXI1DvsD.rlWdqTxvBvV1A2D1MTSxMTVlAmx2MwEwBQuvAwyzLzSuMQVmBGywMvVfVzyuqPV6ZGL0ZGR0ZwV4BK0.GqCV776HuV8cYzOe8glWbslYcfHKcpocpAKctwmI5T0`

leads to the token

`eyJjbGFzcyI6ImludGVybmV0IiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJqdGkiOiI1N2Q1ZGFkZGIyNzk2ZjRjODhiNjlmYmFhZDIzOTljZiIsImlhdCI6MTY0MTE0MjI4OX0.TdPI776UhI8pLmBr8tyJofyLpsUXpcbpcNXpgjzV5G0`.

You therefore need to do at least two requests for your scraping. A first HEAD one to grab the headers of the original HTML page, so that you get a session cookie in return. Then you make GET requests to any of the API endpoints.

Up to you to translate that in Python.